# Rails issue with google map array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I am outputting a google map via this div tag with rails 5.1:

```
<%= tag.div nil, id: 'map', data: { incidents: @incidents.to_json(methods: [:address]) } %>
```

In my show method if @incidents is set to Incidents.all all of the pins display on the map. I am trying to display just the one pin for the record I am on. If I have `@incidents = Incident.find(params[:id])` the pin does not display on the map.

Any ideas on why this is?

Comment: do you see any error on the browsers console?

Comment: Yes I do: Uncaught TypeError: incidents.forEach is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's expecting an array of incidents, not just one. Wrap it like `@incidents = [Incident.find(params[:id])]`.

Comment: That did it. Thank you!